# Windows.old event viewer logs

Tags: windows, security, events, logging, event-viewer

Is it possible to see old event log files, those that you can see in event viewer? But I only have windows.old folder available.

Situation is that, that some of our company's computers were hacked. I want to check if mine was affected too.

A few days ago I have updated windows 8.1 to Windows 10; now all event viewer logs are gone. But I have a `windows.old` folder with files on C: drive. How can I retrieve event viewer logs from there?

Answer (score 2):

The events are stored by default in "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs" (.evt, .evtx files) . If you can locate them, you can simply open them in the Event Viewer application.